# How to get container registry pubsub notifications inside code (java or any other lang)

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-pubsub, google-container-registry

My aim is to get notifications from google container registry in code whenever any image is updated/inserted/deleted from the registry.

I am following tutorial - https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/configuring-notifications

I am able to pull notification messages from the registry using the google console using command - gcloud alpha pubsub subscriptions pull SUBSCRIPTION

But I want these notification messages to be delivered in code (in java).

If someone can give me any reference to any article or tutorial that will  help.

After comment from dsesto i have added following code. This code gave me some messages when i run first. But after that  i kept application running and tried to delete/insert images from container registry but it did not gave any message.
Any suggestions.

```
package com.avaya.ipoffice.mcm.googleconnect;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.AckReplyConsumer;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageReceiver;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectSubscriptionName;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;

@Service
public class RecieveMessagesUtil {      
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        String projectId = "xxxxx";
        String subscriptionId = "prashantsub";

        ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);
        // Instantiate an asynchronous message receiver
        MessageReceiver receiver = new MessageReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
                // handle incoming message, then ack/nack the received message
                System.out.println("Id : " + message.getMessageId());
                System.out.println("Data : " + message.getData().toStringUtf8());
                consumer.ack();
            }
        };

        Subscriber subscriber = null;
        try {
            // Create a subscriber for "my-subscription-id" bound to the message receiver
            subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver).build();
            subscriber.startAsync();
            // ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while subscribing" + e);
        } finally {
            // stop receiving messages
            if (subscriber != null) {
                subscriber.stopAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to share Project IDs, topic/subscription names or any other type of information belonging to your specific use case. Please consider obfuscating them with a placeholder like `PROJECT_ID`.

Comment: By having a look at your code, I see that you do not keep listening, so I suspect you may only be listening to the first bunch of msgs, and then do not retrieve more. Why don't you try using the [example provided in the official repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/pubsub/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/pubsub/SubscriberExample.java)? Have you checked the comments I posted in my answer? Also, you have posted a new question in this post, being the first one already answered. Would you consider posting a different one for the new issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I understand that you have already successfully setup the [notifications system of Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/configuring-notifications) using Pub/Sub topics and subscriptions, given that you said that you are already able to retrieve the messages from your Pub/Sub subscription using [command `gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/pull). Therefore, it looks like your concern is mostly related to pulling messages from a Subscription programatically.

First of all, I would recommend you to have a look at this documentation page about [Subscribers in Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#push_pull). Especially, have a look at the ***Pull vs. Push*** comparison, where you will have a better idea of the possibilities available, and you should first decide whether to work with a **Pull Subscription** (such as the one you are using when calling the `gcloud` command, where the application initiates requests) or with a **Push Subscription** (where Pub/Sub initiates the requests to a subscriber application, such as an App Engine application).

Once that is clear (and assuming that you go for the Pull Subscription, which you are already using with `gcloud`), you can have a look at the documentation on how to perform [Asynchronous Pull operations](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull), with a Java-based example. Additionally, you can have a look at the complete [subscriber example available in GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/pubsub/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/pubsub/SubscriberExample.java).

Finally, you should have a look at the [Client Libraries documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java), more specifically the [Pub/Sub Java reference](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/package-summary.html), where you will find the complete documentation for the Pub/Sub Client Libraries used to work with Pub/Sub programatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I tried following code it worked once and gave me multiple messages but after that even though i have deleted/inserted container registry image it is not giving me any message. Please note i have kept application running.

Comment: I am glad I could help! If the answer was useful for you, please consider [accepting and upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer so that the community sees it solved your issue.

Comment: Regarding your followup question, can you check if messages are being published into your topic by stopping the Java application and using the `gcloud` command to pull them directly from the subscription? Additionally, you can work with [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/metrics-explorer) to see the message publications in the topic and the state of your subscriptions. If the issue about pulling programatically is solved, you may consider creating a new question for this other issue, if you do not manage to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the [Cloud Pub/Sub documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/), particularly, the [subscriber guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#pubsub-pull-messages-async-java), which gives you the code necessary to receive messages in Java.